# Strange behavior when iterating over HTMLCollection from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, getelementsbyclassname, htmlcollection

I wrote a function to change the class of elements to change their properties. For some reason, only some of the elements have changed. It took me a few hours to find a solution, but it seems odd to me. Perhaps you can explain this to me.

This isn’t working:

```
function replace(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('classOne');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].className = 'classTwo';               
  }
}
```

[See the JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UstH6/1/): only every second item is affected; only every second red element changes color to blue.

So I changed the final expression of the `for` loop to not increment `i` anymore:

```
function replace(){
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('classOne');

  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i) { // Here’s the difference
    elements[i].className = 'classTwo';               
  }
}
```

This works well! It seems as though `push` is called and no increment is needed. Is this normal? It is different from the examples I’ve seen.

Comment: I have never heard the term [“loop coefficient”](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/15562484/1). JavaScript calls the last part of a `for` loop the [“final expression”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for#Syntax) (or [“increment”](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-forbodyevaluation) in certain contexts of the spec) and `i++` an [“increment”](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment) (or, generalized, [“UpdateExpression”](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-update-expressions) in the spec).

Comment: Related: [for...in loop not looping through all properties?](/q/32784922/4642212).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

What's going on is an odd side effect. When you reassign `className` for each element of `elements`, the element gets removed from the array! (Actually, as @ user2428118 points out, `elements` is an *array-like object*, not an array. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object) for the difference.) This is because it no longer has the `classOne` class name. When your loop exits (in the second case), the `elements` array will be empty.

You could write your loop as:

```
while (elements.length) {
    elements[0].className = 'classTwo'; // removes elements[0] from elements!
}
```

In your first case, by incrementing `i`, you are skipping half of the (original) elements that have class `classOne`.

Excellent question, by the way. Well-researched and clear.

Comment: Thank you! sounds right..
but... it is sense programming? "elements" is an exist object, not dynamically object that can change without you?

Comment: @MeNa - While the `elements` variable is local to your function, the array that it references is also accessible to (and maintained by) the DOM. The `className` property of each element actually triggers a setter function within the DOM machinery. One of the side effects of that function is to remove the element from the array that `elements` references. So it doesn't change "without you"; it changes because you changed the `className` attribute of one of its elements. To quote the sages of old: _"That's not a bug; that's a feature!"_

Comment: @TedHopp - Thank you again! now all is clearly. (PS, thanks about the 'while()', it's a nicely and elegant solution.)

Comment: You should probably mention that elements isn't _actually_ an array, but merely an array-like datastructure

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList. A NodeList collection is a live collection, which means that the modification of the document affects the collection. [more](http://help.dottoro.com/ljtrjxbf.php)

Comment: Tnx. Indeed the 'live collection' term explains the point well.

Comment: NOT all NodeList collection is live. Some "fetch" methods such as querySelectorAll(), returns STATIC NodeList which are not affected by subsequent DOM changes.

Comment: It returns an live [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)

Answer (score -3):

Or revert the loop, beginning by length-1 and step down to 0

Comment: Yes, that would work as well, but the question begs for an explanation rather than a solution.