# JavaScript - Difference between Array and Array-like object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been coming across the term "Array-Like Object" a lot in JavaScript. What is it? What's the difference between it and a normal array? What's the difference between an array-like object and a normal object ?

Comment: One is an array, and the other is an object. One has array methods, the other may or may not.

Comment: Array-like object is an object, which you can iterate using regular `for` loop and number indices. Array-like objects are returned from many native DOM methods like `getElementsByClassName()`.

Comment: I think it's not such a bad question. "Array-like" could also imply that the object exposes an `forEach` method for example (it doesn't mean that). Clarifying which characteristics make an object array-like is good :)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

> What is it?

An *Object* which has a *length* property of a non-negative *Integer*, and usually some indexed properties. For example

```
var ao1 = {length: 0},                     // like []
    ao2 = {0: 'foo', 5: 'bar', length: 6}; // like ["foo", undefined × 4, "bar"]
```

You can convert *Array-like Objects* to their *Array* counterparts using `Array.prototype.slice`

```
var arr = Array.prototype.slice.call(ao1); // []
```

> Whats the difference between it and a normal array?

It's not constructed by `Array` or with an *Array literal* `[]`, and so (usually) won't inherit from `Array.prototype`. The *length* property will not usually automatically update either.

```
ao1 instanceof Array; // false
ao1[0] = 'foo';
ao1.length; // 0, did not update automatically
```

> Whats the difference between an array-like object and a normal object?

There is no difference. Even normal *Arrays* are *Objects* in *JavaScript*

```
ao1 instanceof Object; // true
[] instanceof Object; // true
```

Comment: `and so (usually) won't inherit from Array.prototype` Care to elaborate on the "usually" part ? Isn't something not an array-like but an array if it inherits from `Array.prototype` ?

Comment: @Taurus If you set up the prototype in the ES5-
 way for some custom object, you will get Array-likes `Array.isArray(Object.create(Array.prototype)); // false`. If you use ES6+ `class A2 extends Array` and `super`, you will get Arrays `Array.isArray(new A2); // true`

Comment: @Paul_S. I see this as more of a gotcha with the `isArray` method since it uses the internal `[[class]]` property behind the scenes, than it being proof that an object with `Array.prototype` is an array-like, rather, an object that has array methods available to it (via inheriting from `Array.prototype`, this also means it has a `length` property) and is numerically indexed is not an array-like, it is an array.

Comment: So, ES6's extends affect the internal `[[class]]` property ? or is there an entirely different mechanism at play here ?

Comment: @Taurus in an ES5- version, even if you did something like `function Foo() {}; Foo.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype); f = new Foo;` consider how `f[0] = 1; f.length; // => 0`. This means it isn't a true Array as setting an index doesn't have the expected side-effects on length. Doing the same with ES6+ does have side effects on length

Comment: @Paul_S. Ahaaa, so it all has to do with the `length` property automatically updating/not-updaing.

Comment: @PaulS. say there is an array like object `var objSort = {0: 1, 1: 7, 2: 2}`,why it doesnt get sorted by `Array.prototype.sort.call(objSort);
?`

Comment: @techie_28 add a _length_ and it will sort, with no _length_ your object is not an _Array-like_

Comment: @PaulS. Yes that worked.But it sorts only when the starting index is `0`.i.e `var objSort = {1: 10, 2: 30,3: 20,length:3}` doesn't gets sorted like `var objSort = {0: 10, 1: 30, 2: 20}` does
`

Comment: The answer to what's the difference should be this:

"Objects do not have to contain a length property, but Array-Like objects do."

The final statement makes it unclear, which is why people have downvoted the question, above.

Comment: `You can convert Array-like Objects to their Array counterparts`, the true thing is you can convert every object to an empty array by this way. So how can we create an Array-like object which we can be formatted to an array by `Array.prototype.slice` just like on `arguments`.

Answer (score 7):

The famous `HTMLCollection` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection)) and the `arguments` ([documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)) are array-like object that automatically created.

Some quick array-like (e.g `HTMLCollection`) differences between real array examples:

```
var realArray = ['value1', 'value2'];
var arrayLike = document.forms;
```

---

**Similarities:**

The length getter is the same:

```
arrayLike.length; // returns 2;
realArray.length; // returns 2; //there are 2 forms in the DOM.
```

The indexed getter is the same:

```
arrayLike[0]; // returns an element.
realArray[0]; // returns an element. ('value')
```

They are both `objects`:

```
typeof arrayLike; // returns "object"
typeof realArray; // returns "object"
```

---

**Differences:**

In array-like the `join()`, `concat()`, `includes()` etc, methods are not a functions:

```
arrayLike.join(", "); // returns Uncaught TypeError: arrayLike.join is not a function (also relevant to `concat()`, `includes()` etc.)
realArray.join(", "); // returns "value1, value2"
```

The array like is not really an array:

```
Array.isArray(arrayLike); //returns "false"
Array.isArray(realArray); //returns "true"
```

In array like you can't set the length property:

```
arrayLike.length = 1;
arrayLike.length; //return 2; //there are 2 forms in the DOM.
realArray.length = 1;
realArray.length; //return 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, an array is a specialised object. Specialised in that:

- There is a special literal syntax `[ … ]`
- There is a `length` property which is automatically updated
- The array prototype includes the functions that you normally expect from an array

The other obvious feature is that all elements have a numeric index.

From JavaScript’s point of view any object which has a `length` property is close enough to be regarded as an array-like object:

```js
var arrayLikeObject = {
    length: 3,
    name: 'thing',
    '1': 'hello'
};
console.log(arrayLikeObject);
```

The `length` property doesn’t have to be correct. Even in a normal array, it’s possible to force the `length` to be other than the number of actual elements. The missing elements all return `undefined`.

You can convert from an array-like object to a real array using `Array.from()`. This function will take various values, but the simplest is something like:

```js
var arrayLikeObject = {
    length: 3,
    name: 'thing',
    '1': 'hello'
};
var array = Array.from(arrayLikeObject);
console.log(array);
```

From here on, the array has all the usual properties and methods. In the above example, the property `[1]` is copied into the new array, but the element `[name]` is not, since it doesn’t belong in a real array.

The `Array.from()` function also accepts a mapping function as a second parameter. This allows you make any changes you need in transit:

```js
var arrayLikeObject = {
    length: 3,
    name: 'thing',
    '1': 'hello'
};
var array = Array.from(arrayLikeObject,
    (element,index) => element?element.toUpperCase():`Item ${index}`
);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also a performance difference. In this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m9cTaYI95Zc) Mathias Bynens recommends to use array over array-like-object because V8 is optimized for common arrays.

Answer (score -1):

I think, in ES6, something is Array-like if it is iterable (has a `[Symbol.iterator]` property).

Comment: 'Array-like object' is an actual title to a thing that exists. It has defined properties that can be applied concretely to Objects built and used in certain ways.

Comment: You think or you know? According to a statement in this post https://dmitripavlutin.com/javascript-array-from-applications/ you could be right -> Moreover, you can use Array.from() with any object or primitive that implements the iterable protocol

Comment: No. `{ length: 5}` is an *array-like object* but not an iterable.