# (NodeJS) How Can I put UInt16 String directly to Buffer as writeUInt16BE?

Tags: node.js, buffer

As In Node JS buffer Like this, int 450 -> converts into 01C2 as below Image.

[Buffer Input Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NparO.png)

I have some string with already Hex encoded String.

var a = "C2323DAD8D2D";

How Can I put this string into Buffer directly, as it looks like this?

[Buffer C2 32 3D AD 8D 2D]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I achieve this was by creating buffer with `Array-like Object`.

Difference between `Array` and `Array-like object` can be found at here.
[Array vs. Array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object)

```
Buffer.from(object)
```

-> TypeError: First argument must be a `string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or array-like object`.

As the Error Says, Buffer can be created with those types.

```
var buf = {};
buf.length = 3;
buf[1] = "AB";
buf[2] = "CD";
buf[3] = "EF";

var Buf = Buffer.from(buf)
```

It works!