# Why lodash _.filter method works on select options but not vanilla js 's filter method?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

When I want to use js es 5 filter method on options object, code bellow triggers an error

```
var selectObject = element.querySelector(".selectorClass");
let defaultOption = selectObject .options.filter(option => {
         return option.value === "Wanted Value";
    })[0];
```

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'filter'

However if I try the same code with _lodash everything works fine

```
  var selectObject = element.querySelector(".selectorClass");
  var defaultOption = _.filter(selectObject .options, (option: any) => {
         return option.value === "Wanted Value";
  })[0];
```

Do you know why and     possibly how to use filter on select options in ecma script 5 please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, in DOM you will receive something that looks like an array, but in fact it is not. So in your case `options` is array-like, a [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionsCollection). To learn more about those objects, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object)

To fix this, you can `slice` it to an actual array

```
const myOptions = Array.prototype.slice.call(selectObject.options)
```

see https://hackernoon.com/htmlcollection-nodelist-and-array-of-objects-da42737181f9

if you are using es6, you could also use following.

```
// Spread operator
[...selectObject.options].forEach(callback);

// Array.from()
Array.from(selectObject.options).forEach(callback);

// for...of statement
for (var option of selectObject.options) callback(option);
```

credit goes to [this gist](https://gist.github.com/bendc/4090e383865d81b4b684)

Answer (score 1):

In VanillaJS, `filter` is simply a method that belongs to `Array`, hence when you try to use `filter` on an `object`, you will get an error.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: actually we are not talking about objects here, but about those array-like objects within the dom. So in his case he is talking about `options` which is array-like and not realy an object.

Comment: @Luke Can't really understand what you mean by `array-like`, I only know there are a limited primitive `Types` in JS

Comment: Look into NodeList. You can iterate over it, but it is not an array. it is so called array-like, because it might implement the iterator. @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that lodash will automatically filter by keys if it's an object.
Try this:

```
Object.keys(selectObject.options).filter( key => 
    selectObject.options[key] === 'Wanted Value');
```