# Fullcalendar, Resources as function don't work

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I'm working with Fullcalendar and I'm trying to get resources as function

```
resources: function(callback){
          var manageEvent = new ManageEvent();
          var request = manageEvent.getEmployees();

          request.always(function (param) {
            //location.reload();
            var list = [];
            var emp;
            for (var elem in param) {
              emp = param[elem];
              list.push({
                  'id': emp['cp_collaboratore'],
                  'title': emp['cognome_col']
              });
            }

            var t = JSON.stringify(list);

            callback(t);

          });
          request.catch(function (param) {
              alert('errore');
          });
        },
```

I checked the variable 't' through log and it shows the following result:

```
[{"id":"1","title":"name_1"},{"id":"2","title":"name_2"},{"id":"3","title":"name_3"},{"id":"5","title":"name_4"},{"id":"9","title":"name_5"}]
```

but it don't works and shows the following error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: resourceInputs.map is not a function
at ResourceManager.setResources
```

Comment: It's an array-like object, not array. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object

Comment: @LaurynasGerbutavicius that's not the issue. See my answer. The OP is passing a string, not any kind of array. If their variable were not stringified, it would be an array already.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to write

```
callback(list);
```

`t` in your code is a string, because you converted your `list` array into a string using `JSON.stringify()`. But fullCalendar expects an actual array, not a string. It can't run functions or read individual properties from a string.

You can remove the line `var t = JSON.stringify(list);` completely, it's not needed.

Generally the only reason you'd use stringify() is if you wanted to log the value to your console for debugging, or convert the array into JSON if you wanted to send it somewhere else using AJAX. It makes no sense to pass arrays and objects around inside JavaScript as serialised strings, when you can just use the objects themselves.

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Marco no problem. The best way you can thank me though is to mark the answer as "accepted". Click the tick symbol next to the question so it turns green. Thankyou.