# Why Object.assign() splits a string and create an object with multiple keys?

Tags: javascript

If a `string literal` is passed to `Object.assign()`, it will create an `object` having multiple `keys` like this example:

```js
var v1 = 'myTest';
var obj = Object.assign({}, v1);
console.log(obj);
```

What is the reason behind that, instead of returning `{0:'myTest'}`?

Comment: Imagine if you have a long list of keys and values.. It would be better to do it dynamically. The use cases of `Object.assign()` is endless

Comment: `Object.assign` loops through every enumerable key, and the enumerable keys of `v1` are `v1[0]==="m"`, `v1[1]==="Y"`, etc. Perhaps you meant `v1 = ['myTest']`?

Comment: Because strings are iterable and have length... try `new Set('myTest')`

Comment: Where do you expect the `0` to come from, if the property value was `v1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

> The **Object.assign()** method is used to copy the values of all **enumerable own properties** from one or more source objects to a target object. It will return the target object.

So, the string literal `v1` will be coerced to an `object` for the method to work. When the string literal is coerced to an `object`, the [String()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) constructor is used, and you will get an object with numeric-properties, something `array-like` (object with a length property and indexed elements), but **not an array**, i.e, actually the same as if you do `new String(v1)`:

```js
let v1 = "myString";
let obj = new String(v1);
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

**You don't get an Array**:

Just for clarification, the coerced `object` you get from the `string` literal is an `array-like` object but **not** an `array`, as you can see on next test that uses [Array.isArray()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to do the check:

```js
let v1 = "myString";

let strObj = new String(v1);
console.log(Array.isArray(strObj));

let arr = v1.split("");
console.log(Array.isArray(arr));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

For know more about `array-like` objects and differences to arrays, maybe you could give a read to next link:

[JavaScript - Difference between Array and Array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object)

Answer (score -1):

The string acts like an array of characters, so you get a result similar to the following

```js
var o = Object.assign({}, ['m','y','s','t','r','i','n','g'])

console.log(o)
```