# How to keep the correct Object Index Sequence [JS]

Tags: javascript, object, indexing

as the title states, by removing certain items from the `Object`, the `index` `sequence` get's disorganized.

Let's say you have this Object:

```
var oObject = {
0:{"Name0":"Example0", "Number":13},
1:{"Name1":"Example1", "Number":13},
2:{"Name2":"Example2", "Number":13},
3:{"Name3":"Example3", "Number":13},
4:{"Name4":"Example4", "Number":13}
}
```

By removing `[3] Index`, with `delete oObject[3]` you get the following `Object`:

```
var oObject = {
0:{"Name0":"Example0", "Number":13},
1:{"Name1":"Example1", "Number":13},
2:{"Name2":"Example2", "Number":13},
4:{"Name4":"Example4", "Number":13}
}
```

as you can see `oObject-Indexes` got disorganized.

**Question:** Is there an operation that can `delete` `entries` from `Objects` and keep it clean in terms of `indexes` ?

Comment: using an array and removing with `splice`

Comment: [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60990926/). However, I advise using arrays instead of objects with numeric keys.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an *array like* object, you can convert it to an array using `Array#from`, then `splice` the resulting array with the given index and return the array in the original object form using `Array#reduce`:

```js
var oObject = {
0:{"Name0":"Example0", "Number":13},
1:{"Name1":"Example1", "Number":13},
2:{"Name2":"Example2", "Number":13},
3:{"Name3":"Example3", "Number":13},
4:{"Name4":"Example4", "Number":13}
};

const delEntry = (oObject, idx) => {
 const arr = Array.from({...oObject, length: Object.keys(oObject).length});
 arr.splice(idx, 1);
 return arr.reduce((r, a, i) => { r[i] = a; return r; }, {});
}

console.log(delEntry(oObject, 3));
```

---

EDIT

As @VLAZ suggested in the comments, this can be done by directly using array method `Array#splice` on array like objects:

```js
var oObject = {
0:{"Name0":"Example0", "Number":13},
1:{"Name1":"Example1", "Number":13},
2:{"Name2":"Example2", "Number":13},
3:{"Name3":"Example3", "Number":13},
4:{"Name4":"Example4", "Number":13}
};
const delEntry = (oObject, idx) => {
  const o = {...oObject, length: Object.keys(oObject).length};
  Array.prototype.splice.call(o, idx, 1);
  const {length, ...rest} = o;
  return rest;
}
console.log(delEntry(oObject, 3))
```

Comment: You can directly splice items out of an object, so no need for a conversion to an array and back. Array methods are generic exactly so you can execute them on non-arrays.