# How to filter HTML Collection in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have problem with filtering HTML collection. I obtained list of classes as html collection. One of those class have .active class. I need to remove all other classes from this list and left only next one AFTER active class. Please how to do that?

Example of my list:

```
HTMLCollection []
0: div.chapter-list-item.seen
1: div.chapter-list-item.seen
2: div.chapter-list-item.seen
3: div.chapter-list-item.seen
4: div.chapter-list-item.active.seen
5: div.chapter-list-item.seen
6: div.chapter-list-item.seen
7: div.chapter-list-item.seen
8: div.chapter-list-item.
```

My code:

```
let allChaptersItems= document.getElementsByClassName("chapter-list-item");
let activeChapter = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
console.log(activeChapter);
console.log(allChaptersItems);
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can directly query to get the items you want using the [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) selector to prevent matching items you don't want:

```js
const chapters = document.querySelectorAll(".chapter-list-item:not(.active)");

console.log("Found elements:")
for (const chapter of chapters) {
  console.log(chapter.textContent, chapter.className)
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter-list-item seen">One</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen other">Two</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen active">Three</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen">Four</div>
```

Note that [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) returns a NodeList, instead of an HTMLCollection. The difference is that the HTMLCollection is *live* and will change with changes to the DOM, while the NodeList is not. For full explanation see [Difference between HTMLCollection, NodeLists, and arrays of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763358/difference-between-htmlcollection-nodelists-and-arrays-of-objects) Both a NodeList and an HTMLCollection are [array-like objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object) and can be treated the same in most cases.

However, if you already have some elements and want to filter them, you can [convert to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222841/most-efficient-way-to-convert-an-htmlcollection-to-an-array) and then use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to check if the "active" class is not in the list of classes using [`.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/contains):

```js
const existingElements = document.querySelectorAll(".chapter-list-item");

const chapters = Array.from(existingElements)
  .filter(chapter => !chapter.classList.contains("active"))

console.log("Found elements:")
for (const chapter of chapters) {
  console.log(chapter.textContent, chapter.className)
}
```

```html
<div class="chapter-list-item seen">One</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen other">Two</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen active">Three</div>
<div class="chapter-list-item seen">Four</div>
```

Comment: One nit-pick that probably doesn't matter for OP: they had a live HTMLCollection, qSA will return a static NodeList.