# Having trouble with understanding the Method borrowing

Tags: javascript, function

i have a problem understanding this code or with `Method Borrowing` ->

```
   function func() {
      [].join.call(arguments)   //how does this works?
   {
```

join only needs a separator, why we are passing the `this` context value?
and more interesting is that it work!

is there anybody to explain this to me?

:)

Comment: `arguments` is an array-like object, but it doesn't contain `join` method. You're borrowing `join` from an array, and call its `join` method in the context of `arguments`, which then results a string containing the values in the arguments, not the values of the empty array (if you'd pass the delimiter argument too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method is used on functions, it behaves in a similar way to using `()` to call a function such as when you perform `functionName()`, however, it allows you to explicitly define what the `this` is inside of the function, so for example:

```js
function functionName(arg) {
  console.log("this", this); // this {"foo": 1}
  console.log("arg", arg); // arg str
}

functionName.call({foo: 1}, "str");
```

Notice that above, the first argument to `.call()` defines what `this` is inside of your function, and then the second argument onwards defines what the arguments are to `functionName`.

We can use `.call()` on any function, including the ones provided to us by JavaScript. In your code, you're using `[].join` which exposes (not calls) the `join` function of arrays, that is, it gives you access to the `join` function defined on the `Array.prototype` object. With that in mind, your code could be rewritten like so to highlight that `[].join` is used just to obtain the `join` function from the array prototype:

```js
function func() {
  const joinFn = Array.prototype.join; // or: [].join;
  console.log(joinFn.call(arguments));
}
func('a', 'b', 'c'); // "a,b,c"
```

Internally, the `.join()` method on arrays uses `this` inside of it (similar to how `functionName()` uses `this` inside of it) to determine what object/array needs its elements to be "joined" together. In your example, you are not calling `.join` directly on your empty array (ie: `[].join()`), but instead, are using the empty array to access the `.join` function, and then calling it with the [`arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) by using `join.call(arguments)`. When you do this, the `this` inside of the `.join()` method is set to the `arguments` object and the join method is called with no arguments, so the separator defaults to `,`. As the `arguments` object is [array-like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707677/5648954) (it has indexes and a `length` property like an array does), its elements can be joined together just like an array's elements can be joined together.

You can see [section 23.1.3.15](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-array.prototype.join) of the ECMAScript specification for further details on how `Array.prototype.join` works internally and how it is made generic to handle array-like objects and not just arrays.