# How to rewrite this ramda.js code in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I am removing ramda from some code I've inherited as part of an effort to reduce the JavaScript size.  But I'm stuck with the below because this line really baffles me as it apparently doesn't operate on any object.

```
var iterate = R.addIndex(R.forEach);
```

The relevant code looks like this:

```
var lis = $(el).find("ul.navbar-nav:not(.navbar-right) > li:not(.nav-more)");

var iterate = R.addIndex(R.forEach);

iterate(function(li) {
    // Other code

}, lis);
```

How can I write it in vanilla JS?

Comment: The `$(el)` is jquery or an alias for querySelectorAll?

Comment: It is jquery.   (wow, how to say that with enough chars for StackOverflow!)

Comment: Are you going to keep jQuery or you're removing it as well?

Comment: jQuery will be removed as well.

Comment: As the answers allude to, `addIndex` just takes a function with a callback that operates on each array element, and returns one whose callback also supplies the array index and the full array, making them more like the `Array.prototype` ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the object to a standard array using `Array.from()` and then you JS `Array.forEach()`:

```
const iterate = (fn, o) => Array.from(o).forEach(fn)

iterate(function(li) {
  // Other code   
}, lis);
```

Answer (score 2):

When [`R.addIndex()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#addIndex) is applied to [`R.forEach()`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#forEach) it creates a function that simply iterates over the items and for each assigns an index starting from zero:

```js
var lis = ["a", "b", "c"];

var iterate = R.addIndex(R.forEach);

iterate(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li, index)
}, lis);
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ramda@0.25.0/dist/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

This is very easy to replace with vanilla JavaScript using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
var lis = ["a", "b", "c"];

var iterate = (fn, list) =>
  Array.from(list)
    .forEach(fn);

iterate(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li, index);
}, lis);
```

In case `Array.from()` is not available and an ES5 solution is needed, then [`Array.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) can be used to convert to array:

```js
var lis = ["a", "b", "c"];

var iterate = function(fn, list) {
  Array.prototype.slice.call(list)
    .forEach(fn);
}

iterate(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li, index);
}, lis);
```

Finally, it is possible to convert to a simple `for` loop that works with any [array-like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object)

```js
var lis = ["a", "b", "c"];

var iterate = function(fn, list) {
  for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
    fn(list[i], i);
}

iterate(function(li, index) {
  console.log(li, index);
}, lis);
```