# Can I use find method to iterate through the characters of a string?

Tags: javascript, find

Can I use find() method to search through a string not an array?

like this:

```js
const text = "welcome";
const output = text.find(letter => letter === "e");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String#split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to convert the string to an array of characters first:

```js
const text = "welcome"; 
const output = text.split('').find(letter => letter === "e");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.find` method to iterate the characters of a string but first you must transform the string to an array of characters, for example:

```
Array.from('string').find(char => char === 't')
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use [`Array#find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) directly on a string. The array methods like `.find()` are intentionally made generic to be usable with any [array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object).

To use an array method on something else, use [`Function#call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```js
const text = "welcome"; 

const output = Array.prototype.find.call(text, letter => letter === "e");

console.log(output);
```

Alternatively, using [`Function#apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```js
const text = "welcome"; 

const output = Array.prototype.find.apply(text, [letter => letter === "e"]);

console.log(output);
```

See also [What is the difference between call and apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply)

Answer (score 0):

Strings don't have a `find()` method.

As suggested in the other answer, you can use `split()` to create an array of characters. But in the case where you're using `find()` with a callback function that just tests element equality, you can use the `indexOf()` method, which exists for both arrays and strings.

```js
const text = "welcome";
const output = text.indexOf("e");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Many ways to convert to an array before being able to use `.find()` (or other array methods).

Here is another using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const text = "welcome"; 
const output = [...text].find(letter => letter === "e");
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const string = 'hello';

const found = string.split('').find(element => element == 'h');

console.log(found);
```

is this what you mean?

find() is originally for finding an array element so you need to convert the string to array and then split it using split() and now you can use the find() to find the string element