# Javascript call method is not working on an Array forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, apply, call

```
var obj = {
    0: 'Asad',
    1: 'Ali',
    2: 'Rizwan'
}
console.log(obj);
let FOREAC = Array.prototype.forEach;

FOREAC.apply(obj , ((item) => {

    console.log('ITEM LOGS');

    console.log(item);

    return true;
}))
```

Above is the code I am using to iterate my object `obj`. It does not show any output.
Thanks In Advance

I am trying to iterate my object `obj`. But my code does not shows any output

Comment: `obj` doesn't have a `length` property...

Comment: Any way to add length property to my `obj`

Comment: `obj.length = 3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple `for..in` loop. This literally what it's made for.

```js
var obj = {
  0: 'Asad',
  1: 'Ali',
  2: 'Rizwan'
}
console.log(obj);

for (const key in obj) {
  console.log('item', key, obj[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the object with index like keys to an array and use it.

```js
const
    object = { 0: 'Jo', 1: 'Ali', 2: 'Jane' },
    array = Object.assign([], object);
    
array.forEach(v => console.log(v));
```

Answer (score 1):

Array methods like `Array#forEach()` are intentionally generic to work with not only arrays but any [array-like object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object). In short, an array-like has indexes as keys<sup>1</sup> and a `length` property<sup>2</sup>.

The following object has indexes but not a `length` property:

```
var obj = {
  0: 'Asad',
  1: 'Ali',
  2: 'Rizwan'
}
```

Once `length` is added `Array#forEach` can be used against it using `Function#call()`:

```js
var obj = {
    0: 'Asad',
    1: 'Ali',
    2: 'Rizwan',
    length: 3
}

let FOREAC = Array.prototype.forEach;

FOREAC.call(obj, (item) => {
    console.log('ITEM LOGS');
    console.log(item);

    return true;
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Or `Function#apply()`:

```js
var obj = {
    0: 'Asad',
    1: 'Ali',
    2: 'Rizwan',
    length: 3
}

let FOREAC = Array.prototype.forEach;

FOREAC.apply(obj, [(item) => {
    console.log('ITEM LOGS');
    console.log(item);

    return true;
}]);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

<sup>1</sup> non-negative integers 
<sup>2</sup> also a non-negative integer. It should show the next available index.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Object.entries to iterate over all pairs in an object.

```
var obj = {
   0: 'Asad',
   1: 'Ali',
   2: 'Rizwan'
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
   console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
}
```

Edit: However as your object does not contain any information in the key position (only indexes) you could also use Object.values to generate an Array from the object values:

```
var obj = {
   0: 'Asad',
   1: 'Ali',
   2: 'Rizwan'
}

console.log(Object.values(obj)
```