# React list elements does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Here I am trying to render my tasks' titles in a list. But for some reason they don't render. Here is the `MyTasks` component:

```
const MyTasks = (props) => {
  const tasks = [...props.tasks];
  console.log(props.tasks, "props.tasks");
  console.log(tasks, "tasks");
  console.log(tasks[0], "tasks[0]");
  return (
    <ListGroup className="mx-2 mt-4">
      {tasks.map((task) => {
        return <ListGroup.Item key={task.id}>{task.title}</ListGroup.Item>;
      })}
    </ListGroup>
  );
};

export default MyTasks;
```

I tried `console.log` inside the component but for some reason I can't access the array elements but I can view the `props.tasks` array.

In my `TaskLists` component I am rendering the `MyTasks` component.

`TaskLists` component is using a useState hook for updating the `tasks` prop value of the `MyTasks` component but during the child component re-render I am not able to access the elements in the `props.tasks` array.

```
const TaskList = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const getTasks = () => {
  //code to get tasks data from data base
  setTasks(taskList);
};
  return (
    <ListGroup className="mx-2 mt-4">
      <MyTasks tasks={tasks} />
    </ListGroup>
  );
};
```

[Here is my `console.log` screenshot, I cant access the array elements for some reason.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EBOV.png)

Comment: `props.tasks.indexOf(i).id` probably throws an error `cannot access id of undefined`. Replace it with `element.id`

Comment: @Martin as you can see from the tagged picture`props.tasks` is an array and has index of 1 and 2

Comment: Instead of props.tasks, you have to use props.tasks[0] in the map.

Comment: @Martin tried replacing it with `element.id` it is still the same

Comment: @MaulikPatel I have used the `forEach` loop on the `props.tasks` array that has tasks objects and tried to push them into `let list` array

Comment: Are you sure you are using the `ListGroup.Item` component properly? Where does that component come from? What happens if you just replace it with a `div`? [Here is your code](https://codepen.io/denk0403/pen/MWzYPQp?editors=0010) working without `ListGroup.Item`.

Comment: Please add a [mre]. And use `map()` no need for that forEach and `list` array.

Comment: @DennisKats I have tried replacing `ListGroup.Item ` with just `li` still it doesn't work.

Comment: @ash543210 It seems like then there is some other code that you're not showing us that is the source of your issue. As mentioned above, please try to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can better assist you.

Comment: Perhaps check that your UI isn't hidden by some CSS

Comment: @DennisKats in the above code when i tried logging the`element` object, there is nothing in the`console`

Comment: @ash543210 Do you mean `console.log(element)` prints `undefined`? Can you try logging `console.log(JSON.stringify(props.tasks))`?

Comment: @DennisKats no what I mean is it doesn't log anything at all. everything inside the`forEach` loop.

Comment: It sounds like initially and at render time `props.tasks` is an empty array. That's why `console.log(element)` isn't printing anything, because the `forEach` loop never runs on an empty array. However, by the time you inspect the value in the console, the `props.tasks` array has been mutated by reference with new data. Are you fetching tasks asynchronously? Again, this would be easier to debug if you edited your question to include how `<MyTasks>` is used, and how `tasks` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

`props.tasks.indexOf(i)` is attempting to return the index of the element `i`, however `i` itself is the index! Instead, try using `element.id` as suggested in the comment above.

Comment: I just realised it changed the code but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to `console.log` inside the foreach, so verify first the values you are getting inside the loop. If you can get then it should print, otherwise you will get to know where is the issue.

Comment: I just did and it's the same as from the first picture

Comment: can you please paste the output of props, as you shared with us as screenshot. It is hard to replicate from the screenshot. I like to try in code, so I can help you better

Comment: I have posted the screenshot for both `props` and `props.tasks`

Comment: As @dennis-kats says if you are getting the value from a asynchronous call, then use asyn await so it would wait for the response, then do the operation.

Comment: No, i am getting the value from a component state value using `useState()`

Comment: @ash543210


I think you are getting array-like object instead on array. I have faced an issue in array-like. Please check the below link, it may help

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707568/javascript-difference-between-array-and-array-like-object