# What makes an empty object qualify as an Iterable or Array-like object?

Tags: javascript, object, is-empty

Given `Array.from` takes an [iterable or array-like object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) as it's first argument, why does it not throw an error when passed an empty object, like this:

```
let emptyObject = Array.from( {} )
```

At iterable is defined as an object that implements the [iterable protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterable_protocol) or the [iterator protocol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#the_iterator_protocol).  An empty object seemingly does neither:

```js
let emptyObject = {}

console.log(emptyObject[Symbol.iterator])
console.log(emptyObject['next'])
console.log(Array.from(emptyObject))
```

An Array-like object has a `length` property and can be indexed ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29707677/2487517)).  An empty object does not have a `length` property.

```js
let emptyObject = {}

console.log(emptyObject['length'])
console.log(Array.from(emptyObject))
```

How does an empty object qualify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.from()` works with array-like objects. More specifically it only really needs the `length` property:

```js
console.log( Array.from({length: 5}) ); //array with 5 slots
```

This is [defined in starting at step 7. of the Array.from algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.from)

> 23.1.2.1 Array.from ( *items* [ , *mapfn* [ , *thisArg* ] ] )
>
> [...]
>
> 7. Let *arrayLike* be ! ToObject(*items*).
> 8. Let *len* be ? LengthOfArrayLike(*arrayLike*).
>
> [...]

[`LengthOfArrayLike` is only this step](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-lengthofarraylike):

> 7.3.18 LengthOfArrayLike ( *obj* )
>
> [...]
>
> Return ℝ(? ToLength(? Get(*obj*, **"length"**))).

Which means to retrieve the value of the `length` property of an object and defer to [`ToLength`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/abstract-operations.html#sec-tolength) to convert it to a number. `ToLength` is defined as the following:

> 7.1.20 ToLength ( *argument* )
>
> [...]
>
> 1. Let *len* be ? ToIntegerOrInfinity(*argument*).
> 2. If *len* ≤ 0, return **+0**.
> 3. Return (min(**len**, 2<sup>53</sup> - 1)).
>    Therefore a missing `length` means `argument` is `undefined` which at step 1. would be converted to zero.

Comment: Right, except an empty object *does not have* a `length` property, so it should not qualify as either an iterable or array-like object.  Do you think this is an error in the `Array.from()` spec or an oversight in the implementation?

Comment: From [step 6 of the Array.from algorithm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.from): "NOTE: items is not an Iterable so assume it is an array-like object".  Seems like this may be an incorrect assumption.

Comment: @Tibrogargan neither an error, not an oversight. The spec says that `LengthOfArrayLike` should get the the value of `length` property. If that value is `undefined` (either because the property if not there or it's explicitly `undefined`) it will return `0`. That's it. I see no basis of this being an *incorrect* assumption. Seems to just be a *safe* assumption. The method accepts iterables or array-likes. If it's not one, then it's the other. If the input is an empty object, then an empty array seems a sensible result. And even a non-empty object can just be represented as an empty array result

Comment: To be a bit pedantic, at the time that assumption was made (step 6) the argument may not have been an array-like object.  The next step coerces it into one.  I believe step 6 may be more correctly stated "NOTE: items is not an Iterable so assume *caller intends it to be* array-like object".  If it already was an array-like object, step 7 is unnecessary.

Comment: This answers the question I asked, but I think not the question I should have asked.  It helped a lot figuring that out though.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it create just an empty array for values not qualified as iterable or array like except `null` and `undefined` since no iterator can be read from them (you can read an iterator from non-nullish values, it just will be `undefined`). So with no iterator fetched just an empty array is created.

```js
console.log(Array.from(1));
console.log(Array.from(false));
console.log(Array.from(null));
```

Comment: It does seem that way, but that behavior is not compatible with [the description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) found on the MDN website (which could be wrong).

Answer (score 0):

When passing a non-empty argument, it seems it checks `[Symbol.iterator]` first, if it doesn't exist, it then checks `length` property. If neither of them exist, fallback to an empty array.

```js
// Neither `length` or `[Symbol.iterator]` exist, empty array
const arr1 = Array.from({});
console.log('arr1', arr1);

const arr2 = Array.from({ length: 2 });
console.log('arr2', arr2);

const arr3 = Array.from({ *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* [1, 2, 3] } });
console.log('arr3', arr3);

// Both `length` and `[Symbol.iterator]` exist, using `[Symbol.iterator]`
const arr4 = Array.from({ length: 2, *[Symbol.iterator]() { yield* [1, 2, 3] } });
console.log('arr4', arr4);
```