# Output all items from an HTMLCollection

Tags: javascript, html

I have an `HTMLCollection` that I have converted from a string:

```
let el = document.createElement('html');

el.innerHTML = data; // This data is my HTML string

let allArtistTiles = el.getElementsByClassName('artistTile');

console.log(allArtistTiles); // I used this to check I see the HTML Collection

let artistsPlaceholder = document.getElementById('artistsPlaceholder')

artistsPlaceholder.innerHTML = allArtistTiles
```

It’s the last line I’m not sure about. How do I actually show all the elements in the `HTMLCollection`? Do I have to iterate through the HTMLCollection? Also, is it necessary to convert the HTMLCollection into an array?

Comment: `innerHTML` expects a string, not an object. Use `artistsPlaceholder.append(...allArtistTiles);` if you can use [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append).

Answer (score 0):

`artistsPlaceholder.innerHTML = allArtistTiles;` wouldn’t work because the `innerHTML` setter expects a string. You need to append the items. In modern browsers you can use

```
artistsPlaceholder.append(...allArtistTiles);
```

which needs support for both [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Browser_compatibility) and [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append#Browser_compatibility).

---

Alternatively, you can write

```
Array.from(allArtistTiles).forEach((elem) => artistsPlaceholder.appendChild(elem));
```

which uses [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Browser_compatibility) (which can be replaced by `Array.prototype.slice.call`), [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach#Browser_compatibility) and [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility) (which can be replaced by regular functions).

---

If you’re going to use `for` loops, it’s still advisable to loop over the array (e.g. from `Array.prototype.slice.call(allArtistTiles)`) to avoid [unexpected `HTMLCollection` behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15562484/4642212).

It’s not strictly necessary to convert the `HTMLCollection` to an `Array`, but an `Array` is easier to work with.